# How can I enable my HP Wi-Fi when it doesn't show in the network menu?

Tags: settings, wifi

I can't use Wi-Fi on my HP Notebook as the network menu only shows Ethernet.

```
   description: Network controller
   product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14E4:4365]
   vendor: Broadcom Corporation [14E4]
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   version: 01
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:91200000-91207fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10EC:8136]
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. [10EC]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 07
       serial: [REMOVED]
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:117 ioport:1000(size=256) memory:91100000-91100fff memory:91000000-91003fff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

Comment: Could you run this in Terminal and paste the output here?  `lshw -numeric -sanitize -C network`  It should give all info on your network adapters. Also, make and model of the notebook would help.

Comment: Reboot after installing bcmwl-kernel-source. If it still does not work, run `rfkill unblock wifi` and then `rfkill list all` Also what kind of HP?

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the Internet via Ethernet please try the following:

`sudo apt update && sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source -y`

Comment: done, and now??

Comment: That was it. That always worked for me with that chipset on my builds. You can also try:

```sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras && sudo modprobe wl```

Answer (score -1):

1. you mast have access to the Internet - smartfon+usbmodem
2. sudo apt-get update
3. sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
4. sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
5. sudo modprobe b43
6. sudo reboot

mast OK